# How to get data for hidden series in Hightcharts / Highstock?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm using [highcharts / highstock](https://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo) and their [documentation](https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/chart.events.addSeries).

I need to dynamically add a series (once after the original chart data is loaded) and I need to hide the series to not be shown into the chart (but still to exist).
The reason for this is, I need to apply indicators to a certain time range and for this I'm using the hidden series (which actually works).

I also need to be able to access to the data of the hidden series at any time, but here is where my issue appears. If I try to access to my hidden series like:

```
console.log(chart.get('hidden-series').data);
```

then this returns an empty array.

**I have the full code in the following [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/delux123/xrmo45Lc/)** and here is a short explanation of what I'm doing there:

With a click on the first two buttons, I'm dynamically adding two series `series2` and `series3`. One of them is added "normally" (it's visible) and the other is added to not be visible on the chart (using the `false, false` as second and third parameters in the method `addSeries` - which I'm not sure what actually this means, since this was a legacy code and I can't find the proper documentation for this anywhere).

And then with the last buttons I'm trying to get the data for each of the series. As you can notice from my test example, even that the `series3` is added (it's not visible) when trying to get the data, it's an empty array.

If I comment the two `false` parameters in the line:

```
}, false, false);
```

the data will be retrieved as expected, but the series will be displayed (and this is not what I want).

Is there any other way for getting the data from invisible series? Or maybe the proper description for the parameters in the `addSeries` method can also help in understanding the issue.

**EDIT:** *(add the reason why I need this, based on the comments below)*

The reason that I need this feature is: I need to have the [VWAP indicator](https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/series.vwap) on the chart and to be applied only for the current day (so starting from 00:00 until the current moment), while the chart itself contains data for multiple days.

So what I'm doing is: I'm taking the subset of the data that represents the current day only, hide this subset and use it's data to show the VWAP indicator only for this certain time range.

The initial load of the indicator works as expected. I need to have access to this data, since the chart is updating in real time and I need to be able to dynamical add new points in the general series of data and but also in the hidden subset for the current day as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding docs: you use only part of docs, the one describing **options**, not **methods**. You can find methods and props in "Classes" tab, for example `addSeries`: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#addSeries - the params you have set to `false` are `animation` and `redraw` - definitively not what you want to achieve :)

To achieve what you need you should:

- add the third series just like the first one (with `redraw=false`)
- hide this series with [`series.visible`](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.visible) and [`series.showInLegend`](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.showInLegend) options set to false (if you have disabled legend, no need to set `showInLegend`)

Now the question is why you need `series.data`. The only reason to use Point Class instances is to call methods like `point.remove()` or `point.update()`. Since that one series is always hidden, then I think it's not the case.

If you don't need real Points, just some data from it, then you always have access to the dataset you used to create the series, right? Like `chart.addSeries({ data: [ ... ]})`.

Anyway, you can force generating points this way: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/nqsemy3z/2/ - note that `series.processData()` and `series.generatePoints()` methods **are not part of API**.

Comment: and do we need the top section of your fiddle, where you are adding an event `fafterRender`, as I'm not sure that I understand what is that for?

Comment: Nope, that was my playground, cleaned the demo up :) Sorry for the confusion! Anyway, why do you need access to `series.data`?

Comment: I have edited my question, by adding the reason at the end of it. What also is not clear for me, from where the methods  `series.processData()` and `series.generatePoints()` comes from? I see they are very important for this to work.

Comment: See my note: "(...) methods are not part of API". Those are internal methods. I missed your update, thanks! `VWAP` indicator listens to data updates, so using `setData()` should be fine in your case, take a look: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/qz8nhmox/ - there are two hidden series that are the base for the indicator. Technical indicator series does not need `series.data` at all :)